# Why am I getting an error in this Pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, lwjgl

I use maven and copied this Pom.xml directly from the lwjgl customize website, why am I getting the error "the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed" at the ""?

```
<properties>
    <lwjgl.version>3.3.0</lwjgl.version>
    <joml.version>1.10.3</joml.version>
    <lwjgl.natives>natives-windows</lwjgl.natives>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: xml file must have one root element. In that case, all elements must be under root element "project" like that: https://gist.github.com/13yo/1662915

Comment: Thank you that solved it

Comment: That is not a valid xml document, please post your complete `pom.xml`. Have you tried any online [xml validators](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)?

Comment: Please check the full documentation how a pom.xml file has too look like https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 0):

xml file must have one root element. In that case, all elements must be under root element "project" like that: gist.github.com/13yo/1662915